# How do I output the entire page template?

Tags: 7, theming, routes, hooks

I've created a custom module that defines a menu callback; that menu path will call a function which performs some actions and once it's finished, it needs to display the theme with a message as the body.

This used to be doable using `theme('page', $message)` but in Drupal 7 it only returns the HTML content that would normally appear within the BODY tags.

I know that there is now a `html.tpl` template, but I'm unsure how I can combine the two to generate a full page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn out that you have to return a render array instead of HTML markup like you could of in Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wild guess but have you tried:

```
$html = array('page' => $message);
theme('html', $html);
```

(or something along those lines)?

Comment: Yes! ;-) It just returns the html but not the body.

Comment: you tried passing the body content to the template as a variable?

Comment: Good point, I'll give that a go.